# How to connect to an S3 bucket using a role ARN is C#

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I was using AccessKeyId and secret to connect and manage my private S3 bucket, used by my application.

Devops is saying I need to use a role they have created for me specifically for this use case to eliminate the need for access and secret keys.

How do I assume a role to manage this S3 bucket access in my C# code?

I would think a role is created, a user is assigned that role. Using access/key you assume that user's rights and then you connect to AWS services.

Am I missing something?

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/AuthUsingTempSessionTokenDotNet.html

Comment: thank you for the link. But the sample uses accessKey and secret as stated below.                 var sessionCredentials =
                    new SessionAWSCredentials(credentials.AccessKeyId,
                                              credentials.SecretAccessKey,
                                              credentials.SessionToken); my code currently does that but I need to replace it with a role

Comment: If the role is assigned to the instance you're running the application on, you just don't specify any credentials at all. It will use the machine role by default.

Comment: I am not running on any AWS instance of any sort. The only thing related to my app and AWS is the S3 bucket unfortunately. Not a very typical use case. We are moving our very large images to an S3 bucket.

Comment: Is this role an IAM role associated with a Cognito Identity?

Comment: Users can also assume roles if they have the permissions to do so.        https://docs.aws.amazon.com/code-samples/latest/catalog/dotnet-STS-AssumeRole-AssumeRole.cs.html

Comment: I have to test this but yes it appears to be what I might be able to use, just worried about the timeout.

Answer (score -1):

A role is a short-term credentialed way of assigning privileges, normally to a service like Lambda, or an EC2 instance; you should assign the role you have been created to the instance from which you are accessing your S3 bucket.

Comment: If I understand your comment, this role can work for AWS resources such as Lambda or EC2 instance. My application is not running on any AWS services at all.

Comment: then you need to check with devops to see what exactly the 'role' is that they have created for you

Comment: So I think what they expect is to use something of the sort of aws sts assume-role  to take on that role for my environment to play nice with AWS using this role. Makes sense?

Comment: I see, so you'll have to get your temporary creds via a web identity or SAML authentication request